# count number of unique elements in a given column after filtering in R

Tags: r, count, unique

Lets say I have a data table like:

```
year  city
2026  NYC
2026  NYC
2026  NYC
2026  LA
2027  LA
2028  NYC
2028  NYC
```

Which can be created by:

```
dt <- structure(list(location = c("NYC", "NYC", "NYC","LA", "LA", "NYC", "NYC"), 
                     year = c(2026, 2026, 2026, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2028)),
                     class = "data.table", 
                     row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I want to count number of unique cities in a given year. Lets say `2026`.
So, the outcome in this case would be 2, because there is just `NYC` and `LA`.
What goes in the last line of following?

```
dt %>% 
filter(year == 2026) %>%
What goes here?
```

Comment: Use `n_distinct` ? `dt %>%
  filter(year == 2026) %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(city))` Or add `..%>%
  pull(count)` to get it as a vector.

Comment: `dt %>% filter(year == 2026) %>% distinct(city) %>% count()`, perhaps works, I just realized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `n_distinct` to get the number of unique values

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  filter(year == 2026) %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(city)) 

#  count
#1     2
```

Or add the filtering step in summarise itself

```
dt %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(city[year == 2026]))
```

Or if we want it as a vector we can add `pull(count)`

```
dt %>%
  filter(year == 2026) %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(city)) %>%
  pull(count)
#[1] 2
```

---

In base R, this is equivalent to

```
length(unique(dt$city[dt$year == 2026]))
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[year == 2026, .(count = uniqueN(location))]
#   count
#1:     2
```

---

Or with `base R

```
length(table(subset(dt, year == 2026, select = location)))
#[1] 2
```